# PCRE regex for string with delimiter

Tags: delimiter, pcre

I want to construct a PCRE regex for following kind of path string:

```
/root/product/db.main;/root/product/db.part
```

Please note that there are only two path strings separated by semicolon, that's it.

I was thinking of something like this: `[ \t]*([\/\w ._-];+)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the values are made of non-semicolon chars, just use `[^;]+`. Please let know more context, and what tool you are using (I do not mean an online regex tester, what is the target environment where the regex will be used?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex pattern:

```
^(?:\/\w+)+(?:\.\w+)?(?:;(?:\/\w+)+(?:\.\w+)?)+$
```

This matches two or more paths, separated by semicolons.  If you only want to match exactly two paths, then use this:

```
^(?:\/\w+)+(?:\.\w+)?(?:;(?:\/\w+)+(?:\.\w+)?)$
```

### Demo